# etale locally infinitesimal lifting property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, schemes, smoothness

For a morphism $X\rightarrow Y$ of qcqs schemes, one has the usual notion of formal smoothness which says that for a pair $(R,I)$ with $I^2=0$, if there is a point $y\in Y(R)$ such that $y_{\vert R/I}$ lifts to a point $x\in X(R/I)$, then one has a lift in $X(R)$.

One can ask for a weaker property where we say that the lift exists only after an étale cover $Spec(R')\rightarrow Spec(R)$.
Do we get an equivalent notion? In the stacks project, Tag. 049R suggests that the answer is yes (and even for fppf topology) but there are no proof.